# Can't connect to a kubernetes service, error: time out

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to connect to `kubernetes` service through a pod.

I can list down the service using `kubectl get svc` and I can see the CLusterIP and port are there, but when the pod tries to connect to it, I get the error

> dial tcp 10.0.0.153:xxxx: i/o timeout.

Any idea how to debug that? Or what could be the reason?

Comment: how do you try to connect from Pod?

Comment: I am not actually sure, there is a script that I am running that is running and connecting the pod to the service, any idea what should I look for?

Comment: Please provide result of `kubectl describe svc <service name>`

Comment: One way this can happen is if the service is not correctly using selectors to identify its backing pods. In that case, attempting to connect to the service coordinates from a client pod, or a client outside the cluster will timeout.